# Library item field doesn't show up the remove button

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am using paragraphs and paragraphs library module in my drupal project. The paragraph (Paragraph A) has a text field (unlimited). I don't see a remove button on the field. I only need one item for one page but it shows up more that one fields. Is there a way to remove it?

[image: THe points are what I want to remove]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated delete button. Drupals default behavior (including paragraphs) is to automatically delete every empty field at the end of the list. The empty field you see is just a convinience for faster adding of a new item.

Side node: To delete e.g. the first item of the list, remove the content and drag it to the bottom.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks